# How do I pass information from the Content_script to the popup page? (Chrome extensions)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to pass a saved varliable from the content script to the popup page, so I would be able to simply output it.
For example, if my content script has the following code:

```
var x = 'abc';
```

I would like the popup title to be this varliable.

Comment: Popup's aren't always open, the background page on the contrary is always available. What exactly do you mean with 'popup title'?

Comment: It doesn't have to be it's title. It can be any type of text... I just want to input this varlible as a string inside the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways to do this, I used the first one in my extension:

1. `localStorage`. Use `sendRequest({})` to pass a message with your variable to the background page, which will then save the variable to `localStorage`. Once that's done, your popup can access the variable like `localStorage["x"]`. (It has to go through the background page because at this time, content scripts cannot access `localStorage`)
2. Plain requests. Pray that the popup is open, and try sending it a message from the content script with the variable in it. Note that this is not a good solution simply because the popup might not be open when you try to send it the variable.

Code Example for #1:

```
//sendRequests look like this: sendRequest(message - Object, [callback - Function]);

//API Docs:
//onRequest Listener: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest
//sendRequest Method: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest
//localStorage: http://www.html5rocks.com/features/storage

//From the Content Script
//Send request to background.html, no callback

chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    type: "popup_var", /* In my extensions, because I could often be different types of reqeusts, I use a type variable to identify them */
    my_variable: "Sally sold seashells by the seashore" /* Whatever variable you are trying to send */
});

//In background.html

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.type == "popup_var"){
            /* The type of message has been identified as the variable for our popup, let's save it to localStorage */
            localStorage["popup_var"] = request.my_variable;
        }
    }
);

//In popup.html

console.log( "Variable from Content Script: "+localStorage["popup_var"] );
```

Comment: Can you please show me a code example? I'm not sure how to use the sendRequest(). By the way - Isn't it possible to access the sendRequest directly from the popup?

Comment: Sure, hold on while I edit the answer. And yes, that is what I meant by "Plain requests".

Comment: Thanks. Offtopic: You are really helping me process :)

Comment: No problem ;) I am here to help.

Comment: Hey, I still need some help - localStorage is messing up. Is there any way I can speak with you in a more fluent way? (Chat?)

Comment: Sure. You can email or IM at my GMail address, it is in my profile.

Comment: Did you get my mail? I mailed your Yahoo beacuse I didn't find any gmail account on your profile.